# Can't get access token for a facebook page for an application that has all the right permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

SO community,

I am stuck in my attempt to have an application post automatically to my Facebook page.

These are the steps I took:

A) I authorized my application for all my facebook pages and granted permissions offline_access, publish_stream and manage_pages using

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<app_id>&redirect_uri=<url>&scope=read_stream,publish_stream,manage_pages,offline_access,publish_actions
```

B) I requested the access token for the application with those permissions

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<app_id>&client_secret=<app_secure_key>&scope=manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream
```

C) I now want to get the access token for the page to be able to do the final post using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/feed?<page_access_token>&message=test&id=<page_id>&method=post
```

however getting the page_access_token is where I am failing

This is the call I am trying

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<page_id>?fields=access_token&access_token=<app_access_token>
```

but instead of the page's access token I just get this back:

```
{
   "id": "<page_id>"
}
```

Anyone has any insight what I am missing to get the .

/Thomas

Answer (score 3):

We just managed to get this working in this past couple of days. Here's a summary. I apologize if I am detailing it beyond necessary but a couple of things you have done seem a bit wrong. To sum up your steps:

If you are doing **step_A** correct, which by the looks of the URL seems all right, then at the end of it you will receive a CODE (not the final access token). This will be a redirection using the redirect URL you sent in step A, so make sure your server is accepting a request for that **redirectURL** specified there. It will be in the form `http://redirectURL?code=A_CODE_GENERATED_BY_SERVER` so doing params[code] should get you the CODE.

Step_B might be where you are slightly off. You have send the **CODE** from step_A back to the server. I see that you have set a `scope` parameter again which is now not necessary (it was done in **step_A**). **Step_B** your request URL should look like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE
```

This time Facebook sends back a `Response` **not** using the redirectURL though. If you have the correct **Step_B** request URI you can paste it in your browser location bar and the response will render in your browser itself. You can use an **HTTPBuilder** (that's what I am using) and capture this Response body. It is of the form `access_token=<really_big_string>&expires=<time_to_live>`. Parse this response whichever way you prefer.

This is also an access_token (let's call it `access_token_uno`) and I suppose there is some amount of things you can do using this. I haven't tried it myself though and so we proceed to **Step_C**. I suppose you already know your `PageID`. You have to send back access_token_uno to Facebook in a URL of the form

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<PageID>?fields=access_token&access_token=<access_token_uno>
```

The response will be a JSON block of the form:

```
{
   "access_token": <required_page_access_token>,
   "id": <PageID>
}
```

Parse the JSON block and you are done.

The one minor detail to remember: The redirectURL has to remain the same in **Step_A** and **Step_B** else the thing fails. Also, I haven't yet tried with the `offline_access` permission but I don't think the steps above will change even if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get https://graph.facebook.com/{userid}/accounts for a user with administrative rights to the page. Inside that you should find the access_token for the page.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#app-login

Comment: Thanks tasinet,

But if I try that, replace the userid with my id and tag along the application access token I get this error message

{
   "error": {
      "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}

It seems it does not like the fact that the access token is owned by an application but then its the application that will be doing the post.

Any further help?

Comment: Apparently, you'll need the user's access_token. I had to do this today at work, the only way I found was to get the user's access_token when he visits, then get /me/accounts and save the appropriate access_token somewhere for offline access.