# Facebook Open Graph: Liking a 'fan page' post always shows up as coming from page instead of user

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have done a tremendous amount of searching/reading and tinkering in my attempts to use PHP code (I'll happily use Javascript, but it has exhibited the same behaviour) to Like a specific post on my game's "fan page". My Facebook API calls return success, but the 'Like' always ends up being from the page instead of from my actual Facebook user account.

I'm using the following code:

```
$post = array();  
$post['access_token'] = $sr->oauth_token; //from decoded $_REQUEST['signed_request'];  
$r = $this->facebook->api($fbPostID.'/likes', 'POST', $post);
```

I know my post id is valid. I've stored it from using PHP to make the post in the first place. (I got that working with the help of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507228/cant-get-access-token-for-a-facebook-page-for-an-application-that-has-all-the-r))

I did not start out with the access_token set (as the Facebook docs state no parameters are required to post a like), but added it in my desperate attempts to get the like to show up properly.

One thing that has occurred to me is this: is it exhibiting this behaviour because my Facebook account is assigned as an admin for the page? If so, how can I go about testing this with a non-admin account on a page that isn't yet published?

Hopefully someone can provide insight!

thanks,
brad

Comment: Try going to your page, select "Voice" from the menu at the top of the screen. It probably shows "You are posting, commenting and liking as your page." Click "Change this to me".

Comment: +1 - i believe there's a migration option you can specify on the app which fixes this too - it hasn't yet been applied to all apps as it's a breaking change- check the roadmap for more details